# PHP how to unset a sub-array by key from a sub-array within a multi dimensional parent array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array here that contains a group of duplicate ids each id is set as as array key and the sub array contains a list of ids that also has another array within the same array?

```
DUPLICATES 16

array(16) {
  [19503804]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19501594"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "15539642"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19498944"
  }
  [19501594]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19503804"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "15539642"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19498944"
  }
  [19837033]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19854553"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854565"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854554"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854683"
  }
  [19854553]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19837033"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854565"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854554"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854683"
  }
  [19544216]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19524884"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19560234"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19540264"
  }
  [19854565]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19837033"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854553"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854554"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854683"
  }
  [19854554]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19837033"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854553"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854565"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854683"
  }
  [15539642]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19503804"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19501594"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19498944"
  }
  [19844271]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19341140"
  }
  [19498944]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19503804"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19501594"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "15539642"
  }
  [16399898]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "15436391"
  }
  [15436391]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "16399898"
  }
  [19341140]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19844271"
  }
  [19560234]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19544216"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19524884"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19540264"
  }
  [19854683]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19837033"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854553"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854565"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854554"
  }
  [19540264]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19544216"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19524884"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19560234"
  }
}
```

notice first array?

```
    [19503804]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19501594"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "15539642"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19498944"
  }
```

the "19501594" "15539642" "19498944" also has another array which need to be unset.so at the end in this array only the unique arrays with unique values are given.

and this is the expected output required.

```
array(5) {
  [19503804]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19501594"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "15539642"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19498944"
  }
  [19837033]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19854557"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19854558"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19854553"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "19854565"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "19854554"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "19854683"
  }
  [19544216]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19524884"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "19560234"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "19540264"
  }

  [19844271]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "19341140"
  }
  [16399898]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "15436391"
  }
}
```

This is what i had initially coded as proposed by @Dale in the answer below.

```
$theduplicates = array (
  19503804 => 
  array (
    0 => '19501594',
    1 => '15539642',
    2 => '19498944',
  ),
  19501594 => 
  array (
    0 => '19503804',
    1 => '15539642',
    2 => '19498944',
  ),
  19837033 => 
  array (
    0 => '19854557',
    1 => '19854558',
    2 => '19854553',
    3 => '19854565',
    4 => '19854554',
    5 => '19854683',
  ),
  19854553 => 
  array (
    0 => '19854557',
    1 => '19854558',
    2 => '19837033',
    3 => '19854565',
    4 => '19854554',
    5 => '19854683',
  ),
  19544216 => 
  array (
    0 => '19524884',
    1 => '19560234',
    2 => '19540264',
  ),
  19854565 => 
  array (
    0 => '19854557',
    1 => '19854558',
    2 => '19837033',
    3 => '19854553',
    4 => '19854554',
    5 => '19854683',
  ),
  19854554 => 
  array (
    0 => '19854557',
    1 => '19854558',
    2 => '19837033',
    3 => '19854553',
    4 => '19854565',
    5 => '19854683',
  ),
  15539642 => 
  array (
    0 => '19503804',
    1 => '19501594',
    2 => '19498944',
  ),
  19844271 => 
  array (
    0 => '19341140',
  ),
  19498944 => 
  array (
    0 => '19503804',
    1 => '19501594',
    2 => '15539642',
  ),
  16399898 => 
  array (
    0 => '15436391',
  ),
  15436391 => 
  array (
    0 => '16399898',
  ),
  19341140 => 
  array (
    0 => '19844271',
  ),
  19560234 => 
  array (
    0 => '19544216',
    1 => '19524884',
    2 => '19540264',
  ),
  19854683 => 
  array (
    0 => '19854557',
    1 => '19854558',
    2 => '19837033',
    3 => '19854553',
    4 => '19854565',
    5 => '19854554',
  ),
  19540264 => 
  array (
    0 => '19544216',
    1 => '19524884',
    2 => '19560234',
  ),
)

foreach($theduplicates as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $d){
        if(isset($theduplicates[$d])){
        unset($theduplicates[$d]);
    }
}
// but it totally cleans theduplicates array
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: Probably simple enough, but i cant quite work out what you want to do - could you amend your question to include expected output, plus your existing code you have tried to solve the problem

Comment: essentially, the values in the first top level array are also present as top level arrays and need removing (i think)

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying or need. I dont see a duplicate id of `19501594` nor that it has another array.

Comment: @Steve I have updated the answer the expected output from the above original array needs to be downsized to 5 arrays.

Comment: @Dale Yes that is the complication for me isn't there a way to clean the array based on the top-bottom order and restart the process until its totally cleaned? because on the first loop it unsets the below orders and somehow i need to pass the modified array back to foreach loop so it cleans the rest.

Comment: @CodeGodie those arrays that doesn't have duplicates like 19501594 can be left alone.

Comment: Do a foreach loop though them and `unset()` when you find your match. I think @Dale might be close, to something what you need.

Comment: @codedudey Maybe its just me being a bit slow this morning, but I dont know what you mean by _"Duplicates"_ . When i look at your array keys, they are all unique, I dont see duplicates. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @CodeGodie, Nope mate you are not slow this morning this scenario is crazy. if you look at the array keys and array values you will see that (starting from top) the array values are each ids and most of them has another sub array in the parent array (as their key). i want to remove those.

Comment: @RyanVincent updated the question thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every iteration you want to check they keys that have already been iterated. Therefore you want to keep track of these keys. I would do something like this:

```
$keys = [];
foreach ($main_array as $k => $set) {
    if (in_array($k, $keys)) {
        unset($main_array[$k]);
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($set as $val) {
        $keys[] = $val;
    }
}

var_dump($main_array);
```

This code will also work, but you have to **pass by reference**:

```
foreach ($main_array as &$values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if(isset($main_array[$value])) {
            unset($main_array[$value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I though i am crazy and this is not possible. You just did it.Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question (of which I am doubtful) this code should get you on your way

```
$array = [
    0 => [5, 6, 7],
    1 => [10],
    5 => [10], // to remove
    6 => [10], // to remove
    7 => [10]  // to remove
];

print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if(isset($array[$value])) {
            unset($array[$value]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

output..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: @codedudey how are you initially creating the duplicates array in your question?

Comment: i know its messy, it comes from a pre-developed script the duplicates are stored in database and is created from mysql results for filtering.